# Ruby on Rails app on Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, ruby-datamapper

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I could deploy my rails app to GAE? I've been reading about it, but it seems to be a fairly complicated task.

I tried with the `google-appengine` gem, but its not a piece of cake either.

Has there been any progress with the `DataMapper` adapter or will I need to make changes to my models?

I was hoping to see a full-detail tutorial about it, but those that I found were somewhat out-of-date.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Deploying Rails on Google's App Engine has become a lot easier than it used to be. There are a couple of caveats you should be aware of:

- App Engine only supports the Python and Java environments so for Rails you will be deploying on [JRuby](http://jruby.org/)
- App Engine's datastore is based on BigTable so you won't be able to use ActiveRecord on a relational database (if you want your datastore hosted in AppEngine). But as @Geoff Lanotte as pointed out there is a Datamapper adapter you can use
- Pre-deployment testing is done within Google's sandbox tools as opposed to things like `script/server`

Some other resources you might consider:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/

http://rails-primer.appspot.com/

http://gist.github.com/335023

Comment: I'd like to thank you, although I am quite late in doing so! It really worked, and deployment was piece of cake :-) Thanks!

Comment: Is there any update to this for Rails 3.0 or 3.1 ?  Do the instructions for Rails 3 beta still apply?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy Ruby on Rails on **Google Compute Engine** if it works for you. Compute Engine is Iaas (Infrastructure as a Service) and it is used by Google App Engine, which is PaaS (Platform as a Service).
Compute Engine is one abstraction layer lower (you can access OS resources, like: file system, network etc.).

**Detailed instructions:**
http://startup-with-gae.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-deploy-ruby-on-rails-application.html