# How do I write a route that is SEO friendly in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, custom-routes

I am changing my site over from Google App Engine to rails and I would like to keep my place in google search. Currently my site uses a URL `/page?pid=microsoft-interview-questions` to access the Microsoft subsection of interview questions. How would I create a route that can send this to `'/tags/:id'` where :id would be microsoft in this case?

Comment: Do you want to keep the existing routes, or do you want to send to "tags"? Or both?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. You want to receive this: "/tags/page?pid=microsoft-interview-questions" with "page?pid=microsoft-interview-questions" to be the :id parameter?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I would like `/page?pid=microsoft-interview-questions` to go to :controller => tags, :action => show for the tag titled microsoft.

Comment: It looks like you could deploy rails on Google App Engine... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278745/ruby-on-rails-app-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to josh's answer I'll put this here for formatting:

```
# your controller

def show
  @subject = Subject.find my_stripped_id


private
def my_stripped_id
  params[:id].sub(/-interview-questions/, '')
end
```

Comment: This takes care of the logic part of distilling the id. It seems though, that because of the ? it is passing the parameter as pid instead of id

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work (in routes.rb):

> map.connect '/page?pid=:number',
>   :controller => 'tags', :action =>
>   'show'

see [routes reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: The only problem with that is that I don't know how to parse out the '-interview-questions' after the tag name.