# Deploying Ruby on Rails app to Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, deployment

I am attempting to deploy my Rails application to the Google App Engine, but thus far unsuccessfully. I have deployed the Ruby development stack following the instructions but that is where they stop, there is nothing on how to actually link my app from localhost and deploy to the AppEngine to view in browser.

There is this question: [Ruby on Rails app on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278745/ruby-on-rails-app-on-google-app-engine) answering the problem, but appears greatly outdated.

How can I deploy my Rails App to Google App Engine?

Comment: Do you read [this getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world)?

Comment: Please create a tutorial or provide some steps so that we can deploy it on google app engine Micheal

Answer (score 0):

The quickstart link provided by Michael is useful when you are using just Ruby. If you want to use Ruby on Rails, you can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine).

If you use Cloud Shell for the deployment, to test if the server is working, specify the port you wish to connect to when you launch it:

```
bundle exec rails server -p 8080
```

Follow the steps in the tutorial and you will be able to deploy a Ruby on Rails app on Google App Engine. Then you just have to adapt the steps to your own Rails app and you will be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

**(Jun 2021)**: This question is still relatively current, but all of the comments and single posted answer are now outdated as the [Google Cloud serverless compute platform](http://cloud.google.com/serverless) team formally [launched Ruby as a Standard service in Aug 2019](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/ruby-support-comes-to-app-engine-standard-environment). You can find out how to setup, run locally, then deploy globally, a Ruby app to App Engine from its [Quickstart page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/quickstart). You can learn more about the Ruby 2.5-2.7 runtime on [its platform overview page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/runtime).